# Better way to validate an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a function that removes tags inside a collection, sometimes the parameter can be an Array others times just a variable.

I'm doing the parsing like so, just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it?

I already tried [...tag] but that just split the `string`

```
this.removeNotificationTag = async (userId, tag) => {
    const tagsToRemove = Array.isArray(tag) ? tag : [tag];
     
     // if tag is a variable make it an array.
  };
```

Tried the spread operator, but that just splitted the string.

Comment: Can you add example input and expected output to your question? There's probably no need for that function to be async.

Comment: What you wrote is a common pattern for this, it's fine.

Comment: @Andy I'm doing some db related task that needs to be awaited, if I send tag1 I want to get [tag1] if I send 2 or more tags i.e [tag1, tag2] well just let that through

Comment: Your solution if fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, that's the generic way to do it.

If your input is either `string` or `string[]`, you could also use `typeof`:

```
this.removeNotificationTag = async (userId, tag) => {
    const tagsToRemove = typeof tag === 'string' ? [tag] : tag;
    // the rest of the code...
  };
```

But this is less generic and the code is the same length, so I would stick with what you wrote in the first place.